# Stopping unnecessary operations in Android

Tags: android

I am new in Android. I want to write a real time program that take a stream of data from wi-fi
to usb. The stream should pass in 5 ms. Todo this I need to stop any other operations(like UI).
Is there away to do it?

Comment: You can stop all other operations. Android is not a RT OS.

Comment: yeah just put it all in 1 thread...XD

Comment: Can you send me code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there away to do it?

Not except perhaps via custom firmware. As a commenter pointed, Android is not a RTOS. RTOS applications should use an RTOS operating system.